# Adicionar informação num ficheiro .json

Tags: php, json, append

Tem como adicionar informação com uma referência diferente num ficheiro json com php?

Do tipo:

file.json

```
{ 
     'id': 'rt6hj7'{
          'nome':'Miguel'
      },
      'id': 'rt10hg9'{
          'nome':'Sagas'
      } 
}
```

E adicionar o José com o id: 8dhus8763 e não subscrever nenhuma informação já contida no ficheiro. Tornar o file.json numa espécie de base de dados.

Alguém tem uma ideia?

Agradeço ajuda

Comment: Sim é possível apesar de não ser aconselhável. Coloca o código aí.

Comment: "Não ser aconselhável" não é verdade, tudo depende do que ele quer fazer com isso. JSON é uma ótima forma de armazenar configurações diversas da aplicação, e as vezes você precisa modificar essas configurações programaticamente.
Também é interessante usar JSON como uma database em alguns casos **bem específicos**, como por exemplo uma aplicação muito simples que só vai ser usada localmente por apenas um usuário.
Agora @user2647038 caso você queira fazer um web app acessado por diversos users, ou que tenha várias entidades (leia-se tabelas no banco) é realmente desaconselhável usar um JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Sim, é possível, contudo primeiramente note que sua estrutura JSON está inválida, isso aqui não faz sentido `'id': 'rt6hj7'{` então você deve começar usando um JSON válido, ex:

```
{
   "rt6hj7": {
        "nome": "Miguel"
    },
    "rt10hg9": {
        "nome": "Sagas"
    }
}
```

Agora assumindo que essa estrutura acima esteja em file.json, podemos sim adicionar keys com algo como:

```
// pega o conteúdo do file.json e transforma em um php array
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('file.json'), true);
// adiciona "José" sob a id "8dhus8763"
$data['8dhus8763'] = ['nome' => 'José'];
// salva seu novo JSON
file_put_contents(json_encode($data));
```

A ideia é bascimante: pega o conteúdo do JSON -> transforma a JSON string em um PHP array -> adiciona o objeto com "nome": "José" no array, sendo a id "8dhus8763" -> transforma seu PHP array em uma JSON string -> salva a JSON string no arquivo original.